# AOP exception when calling Around aspects on

Tags: spring, aop

I am trying to run a aspect on all service methods. but this seems to fail for the methods which have primitive return type. I am getting this error org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type . is it necessary that all methods for used for aspect needs to have non primitive return types? Thanks

```
  @Aspect
@Component
public class ServiceAspect
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServiceAspect.class);

   @Pointcut("execution(* com.xxx.service..*.*(..))")

    public void perform()
    {

    }

    @Around("perform()")
    public void performTimeCal(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        try
        {
            Date start = DateUtils.newDate();
            String processingTime = null;
            joinPoint.proceed();

            processingTime = DateUtils.computeDateDifference(start,
            DateUtils.newDate());
            LOG.info("STAT: " + getSimpleClassName(joinPoint) + "."
            + joinPoint.getTarget() + "(): " + processingTime);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getSimpleClassName(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        if (joinPoint.getThis() != null)
        {
            return joinPoint.getThis().getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
        return "";

    }

}

   Service Method

   @Service
  public PropertyService
  {
     public boolean isMessageProcessingEnabled()
     {
       // DAO CODE
     }


  }
```

Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public boolean com.xxxxxxx.service.admin.PropertyService.isMessageProcessingEnabled()
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.processReturnType(CglibAopProxy.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:82)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
    at com.xxxxxxx.service.admin.ApplicationPropertyService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a4e8f96.isMessageProcessingEnabled(<generated>)
    at com.xxxxxxx.processBoardMessages(BoardMessageProcessor.java:136)
    at com.xxxxxxx.processMessage(BoardMessageProcessor.java:95)
    at com.xxxxxxx.service.BrdServiceTest.testMessage(BoardServiceTest.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your aspect is wrong. An around aspect **MUST** have the following signature and must always return the result of the call to proceed.

```
public Object aroundMethodName(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, [other attributes) {
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    return result;
}
```

If you don't and have a `void` method basically every method that this advice applies to return `null`.

Comment: what about methods with primitive return type? will the above code work for that also? Do I need to modify the methods to return objects instead of primitive? Thanks

Comment: No... You have to return something. But a primitive cannot be `null`, which is also what the exception tells you (and you are forcing `null` due to the `void` return type which is illegal for a primitive).

Answer (score 0):

When the method is void the proceed method returns null. To log the method i did this:

```
var proceed = pjp.proceed();
var result = Objects.isNull(proceed) ? "void" : proceed.toString();
```

So when i log the result in DEBUG mode it shows "void" instead of crashing or logging nothing.