# Aspect execution not firing on method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am kinda new to Aspects and I am trying to surround a function with an aspect but I can't get it called.

The method signature is as follows:

```
public <T> T get(String uri, List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs, final Class<T> clazz)
```

and it's defined in class with fully-qualified name:

```
com.X.Y.infrastructure.rest.RestClient
```

And the Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class WebRequestTimeLoggerAspect {
   @Around("execution(* com.X.Y.infrastructure.rest.RestClient.get(..))")
   public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("hijacked method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("hijacked arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    System.out.println("Around before is running!");
    Object ret = joinPoint.proceed(); 
    System.out.println("Around after is running!"); 
        return ret;
   }
}
```

I just cant seem to find the problem.
Everything is declared and spring loads both beans into the container.

If possible. How do I add another function to the same execute deceleration?

Thanks.

**Update:**

So I have managed to do some progress, apparently I needed to Change project configuration to support Aspectj (in eclipse) but now I am getting the following error:

```
applying to join point that doesn't return void: method-execution(java.lang.Object com.X.Y.infrastructure.rest.RestClient.get(java.lang.String, java.util.List, java.lang.Class))
```

I will assume that i need to specify the return argument. I thought * will catch all, but that seems to be for void.

So how does the point cut should look for generics like that?

Thanks again

**Another update**

Following the comment I have added a return value to the method. But the aspect is still not firing.

By request the spring configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="webRequestTimeLoggerAspect" class="com.X.Y.infrastructure.rest.WebRequestTimeLoggerAspect" />
```

And in fact I don't believe I need to declare a bean for that aspect because I have package scan. But just in case.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657924/aop-exception-when-calling-around-aspects-on. You have the same problem you are destroying the method call by not returning the result of the call to proceed. If it doesn't work in Spring it has nothing to do with your workspace but all with your spring configuration. (Please post your configuration).

Comment: Grate that solved the compilation error but the Aspect is still not firing... i will update the code in question

Comment: Are the other aspects executing ?

Comment: no they are not, nothing happens. i have to mention as well that i am using STS and it tells me on the ide that the ASPECT is connected to the function and everything is cool. As well i have other aspects in the project and they are working correctly so it seems like its not a problem with the configuration

Comment: Then you have a configuration issue. Try to implement the most simple aspect get it working. Then, focus on the complex one.

Comment: The problem was that the class was instantiated with "new" and not by spring :(